# Time data does not match format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am using a script that someone else created (and another person has been using successfully for months), and I can't figure out this error:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
time data '2022-12-28 14:43:08.908271' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p' (match)
  File ". . .\res-script.py", line 19, in <module>
    end = pd.to_datetime(yesterday, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p").normalize()
```

I'm trying this and still getting the same error:

```
today_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
yesterday = datetime.today()

end = pd.to_datetime(yesterday, format='%Y-%m-$d %H:%M:%S').normalize()
```

Comment: The time data string is `2022-12-28 14:43:08.908271`, which clearly does not match either of the two format strings you tried...

Comment: Come on... `2022-12-28` clearly has hyphens in it and you're using `%Y/%m/%d`

Comment: The `/` really are taken literally. They're expecting `2022/12/28` not `2022-12-28`.

Comment: Apologies, I mistyped my question, but I've fixed it. I did try the code with hyphens.

Comment: `%I` only works for up to 12, you want `%H` for a start for `14`

Comment: @roganjosh That makes sense. I'm trying this now and STILL getting the same error. time data '2022-12-28 15:40:30.232204' does not match format '%Y-%m-$d %H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: You know what's most frustrating here? You don't actually have to pass `format` because it's an ISO-8601 timestamp and pandas will fix it for you. But, that feels like a cop-out answer :/

Comment: Well, that pattern can't match because you have sub-second units. The `format` doesn't take nearly-correct matches

Comment: @roganjosh Then should I take out format entirely? I'm brand new at Python and just trying to update a project someone else left for me (and they weren't exactly an expert). I appreciate your help.

Comment: `$d` should be `%d`.

Comment: @Barmar I can't believe I missed that! Thanks!

Comment: @j9pino you _could_ drop `format` here and `pandas` will get it right. For microseconds, you need `%f`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). You can't use hand-wavey patterns for matching, it has to be exact

Comment: Use `format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`

Answer (score 0):

After a few people pointing out the obvious, we have it fixed! Either of these will work:

```
end = pd.to_datetime(yesterday, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').normalize()
```

or

```
end = pd.to_datetime(yesterday).normalize()
```

Comment: The latter works only because the datetime is in ISO-8601 format and `pandas` can handle that. There are other times where you wouldn't want to pass off the format to inference